# How to add the file upload feature to the drupal 8 in an article or basic page with the ability to display the uploaded files on the same page?

Tags: drupal

I installed drupal 8 version on my localhost and created the basic page and articles on the sample site.
Now i want to create a page which has file upload feature and display the uploaded files on the same page.
How can this be done?

Also,How to create a custom block in drupal 8? I tried to create a custom block, but i don't know where to place all of my general html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following link which guides you how to create a custom module in drupal 8

http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/my-first-drupal-8-module

Comment: Dear venky, please try to avoid link only answers, because once the link gets outdated, all information is lost. Instead, add at least the core idea or the basic steps and link the full example as addition, This helps to keep the quality of answers up.